# CUDA Matrix Addition Timing with varying block size

Tags: cuda, gpu

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cuda_runtime.h>
#include<sys/time.h>

#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, const char *file, int line, bool abort=true)
{
   if (code != cudaSuccess) 
   {
      fprintf(stderr,"GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
      if (abort) exit(code);
   }
}

double measure_time()
{
struct timeval tp;
gettimeofday(&tp,NULL);
return ((double)tp.tv_sec+(double)tp.tv_usec*1.e-6);


}
__global__ void sum_matrix(int *a,int *b,int *c,int nx,int ny)
{

int ix=blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
int iy=blockIdx.y*blockDim.y+threadIdx.y;
int idx=iy*nx+ix;
c[idx]=a[idx]+b[idx];
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int dimx=atoi(argv[1]);
int dimy=atoi(argv[2]);

int nx=4096;
int ny=4096;

dim3 block (dimx,dimy);
dim3 grid (nx/dimx,ny/dimy);

double start,end;

int *a,*b,*c;
long long nbytes=nx*ny*sizeof(int);

cudaMalloc((int**)&a,nbytes);
cudaMalloc((int**)&b,nbytes);
cudaMalloc((int**)&c,nbytes);

start=measure_time();
sum_matrix<<<grid,block>>>(a,b,c,nx,ny);
cudaDeviceSynchronize();
gpuErrchk( cudaPeekAtLastError() );
end=measure_time();

printf("Time elapsed = %f ms\n",(end-start)*1000);

cudaFree(a);
cudaFree(b);
cudaFree(c);
return 0;
}
```

Above is a 2d matrix addition kernel that I am using to check the execution time of different blocks size configurations on an MSI GTX 750 1 GB GDDR5 card. Below are the execution time results for different block size configs.

./sum_matrix 32 32
Time elapsed = 3.028154 ms

./sum_matrix 32 16
Time elapsed = 3.180981 ms

./sum_matrix 16 32
Time elapsed = 2.942085 ms

./sum_matrix 16 16
Time elapsed = 3.238201 ms

./sum_matrix 64 8
Time elapsed = 3.020048 ms

./sum_matrix 64 16
Time elapsed = 3.304005 ms

./sum_matrix 128 2
Time elapsed = 2.965927 ms

./sum_matrix 128 1
Time elapsed = 2.896070 ms

./sum_matrix 256 2
Time elapsed = 3.004074 ms

./sum_matrix 256 1
Time elapsed = 2.948046 ms

What I can understand is that increasing the block size to the max (1024 threads) like in case of (64,16) may reduce the available parallelism and hence performs worse. What I don't get is why increasing the block x dimension and reducing block y provides better performance. Is it due to memory coalescing/caching or divergence?

Thanks

Comment: You're running on a dynamically clocked gaming card. This makes timing results pretty volatile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your main problem here is that the differences aren't statistically significant in the first place. For such small amounts of data, it is quite likely that the overhead of actually performing the kernel launch is dominating execution time. Note that all of your times are right around 3 ms regardless of the block size being used.

You could probably get somewhat more precise results by launching the kernel many times in a loop and averaging the execution time, but with such a small kernel invocation, that would probably only serve to confirm that all of the launches are executing in about the same amount of time due to launch and block scheduling overhead dominating actual kernel execution time.

In order to see any statistically significant results from the use of different block sizes, you're probably going to need to do something (much) more significant than just 16 million integer additions.

Comment: I doublt kernel launch overhead is a factor - it's usually of the order 10us.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, as I mentioned in my comment, when timing on gaming cards, especially for such short tests, volatility in the results is expected. They are dynamically clocked, and the clocks won't be the same run-to-run.

In my experience block size/shape is unlikely to have much of an impact in this type of naively implemented element-wise problem. So long as your block x dimension is a multiple of 32, and you have large enough blocks to get 100% occupancy. After that point it's just streaming data in and out.

However, you can do better than your implementation. [This reference](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~volkov/volkov10-GTC.pdf) is getting rather old now, but makes some good points. Essentially, calculating many elements per thread is going to give you better performance.

Another (small) performance improvement will come about from vectorising your memory transactions. If you operate on int4s rather than ints, the hardware can issue 128 byte load/store instructions instead of 32 byte load/store instructions. This is slightly more efficient as you have 4x fewer memory instructions to process.